# relative css колонки блоки позиционирование

Tags: css, css3, разметка, блок

Есть

```
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
```

Для того чтобы разместить блок В рядом с блоком А (справа от блока А), нужен такой код:

```
#a{
positson: relative;
top:0px:left:0px;
widht:100px; height:200px;
}

#b{
positson: relative;
top:-200px:left:100px;
widht:100px; height:200px;
}
```

Но если блок А не имеет фиксированную высоту (в нем будет много или мало текста), то как отпозиционировать блок В?

Если делать блок А `absolute`, то контент, который в нем содержится, выступает и заступет вниз (ниже нижних элементов страницы). Размещение блока В в блоке А ничего хорошего не дает.

Вот такая проблема БЕЗ конкретики. Я выделил, то что не знаю не понимаю.

---

Дописываю:

Хотя, кажется, можно эти два дива поместить в один див. И сделать (назначить свойство) этому диву `justify-content: flex-start;`. 
Не знаю, нужно проверить. Проверю отпишусь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. У Вас грубейшие ошибки в css!

   правильно:

   ```
        #a{
          position: relative;
          top:0px;
          left:0px;
          width:100px; 
        }

      #b{
          position: relative;
          top:-200px:
          left:100px;
          width:100px; 
          height:200px;
        }
   ```
2. > Для того чтобы разместить блок В рядом с блоком А (справа от блока А),
   >   нужен такой код:

   Тут без комментарий вообще (возвращаемся к пункту 1.).
3. Задать, чтобы блок В был рядом с блоком А можно несколькими способами:

   - `inline-block`

     ```
      #a, #b {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
      }
     ```
   - `float: left`

     ```
     #a, #b {
        float: left;
     }
     ```
   - другие (flex, table, ...)

Например:

```css
#a{
  position: relative;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width: 100px; 
}

#b{
  position: relative;
  top:-200px:
  left:100px;
  width:100px; 
  height:200px;
}

#a, #b {
  float: left;
}



/* Стили для наглядности */
#a {
  background: #ccc;
}

#b {
  background: #777;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  контент без фикс. высоты
</div>
<div id="b"></div>
```

без контента:

```css
#a{
  position: relative;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width: 100px; 
  
  min-height: 1px;
}

#b{
  position: relative;
  top:-200px:
  left:100px;
  width:100px; 
  height:200px;
}

#a, #b {
  float: left;
}



/* Стили для наглядности */
#b {
  background: #777;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  
</div>
<div id="b"></div>
```

**Вариант с оберткой `.wrap`:**

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

#a{
  width: 100px; 
}

#b{
  width:100px; 
  height:200px;
}


/* Стили для наглядности */
#a {
  background: #ccc;
}
#b {
  background: #777;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="a">
  
</div>
<div id="b"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Детально еще не разобрался. По поводу ошибок: с точки зрения css--парсера какая разница как написан код: в одну строку или во многих строках. Спорить не буду. Вы более сведущи в этих делах.

Comment: Проблема не в строках, а в написании НЕ `positson`, а `position`; НЕ `widht`, а `width`!

Comment: А строки конечно же не при чем, можно свойства и в одну строку писать, главное разделять их `;`

Comment: ааа, так я это писал прям тут на сайте, а не в IDE. в среде достаточно набрать пару  первых букв. дальше автодополнение работает. Вот наверное потому у меня только по полслова правильно написано.

Comment: Тогда понятно =)

Comment: теперь знаю к кому обратиться для редизайна сайта.  Но сначала нужно доклепать его "я его слепила из того что было..."  Идея моего сайта порвет всем Моск. Ваши контакты у меня.